# Placeholder opacity is override in mui react. Place holder is not shown in mui Textfield

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, placeholder

I'm using a filled variant Texfield from mui react, I modified it using theme component but the placeholder is hidden when it is not focused.
[Before Focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC0W0.png) 
[On Focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xOe7.png)

I used many methods to change the opacity but it is by default set to zero and used important tag by mui itself. No matter what ever i  use to change the opacity, it is being ignored and used the default one from mui. Can anyone help me to fix this.

The class which overrides opacity is :-

```
label[data-shrink=false]+.MuiInputBase-formControl .mui-szobsr-MuiInputBase-input-MuiFilledInput-input::-webkit-input-placeholder
```

[Dev tools screenshot of class which override opacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXHXi.png)

I want to make the placeholder visible the whole time jst like this

[Desired ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xOe7.png)

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful to see your code because I don't have a good idea of how you've structured your component. However, if you want to override the default opacity of the `TextField`'s placeholder, you can try something like this:

```
<TextField
  placeholder='Whatever you want'
  variant='filled'
  inputProps={{
    sx: {
      '::placeholder': {
        color: ({ palette }: Theme) => palette.text.secondary,
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

`sx` is a pretty cool feature MUIv5 has now that lets you style components in a theme friendly way. You can set the opacity to whatever you want, key is to use the `sx` prop within the `inputProps` prop of the `TextField`. You could also just use the `sx` prop of the `TextField` but then you'd have to go through some nested css selectors to target that `.MuiInputBase-input` class to then override that so in my opinion, this is much easier!

Comment: I tried this method but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: hmmmm, update your post to include what your component looks like or put up a code sandbox

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to solve this by increasing the specificity of the `label` by adding the `.MuiFormLabel-root` className as follows (using ThemeProvider):

```
MuiInputBase: {
  styleOverrides: {
    formControl: {
      'label[data-shrink=false].MuiFormLabel-root ~ & ::-webkit-input-placeholder': {
        opacity: '0.42!important',
      },
    }
}
```

This is based on the comment here:
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/8436